# Normalize audio, then reduce the volume in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a question relating to ffmpeg. First here is the scenario, I am working on a project where I need to have some audio with a presenter talking and then potentially some background music. I also have the requirement to normalize the audio. I would like to do this without presenting a bunch of options to the user.

For normalization I use something similar to this post:

[How to normalize audio with ffmpeg.](https://superuser.com/questions/323119/how-can-i-normalize-audio-using-ffmpeg)

In short, I get a volume adjustment which I then apply to ffmpeg like this:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -af "volume=xxxdB" <output>
```

So far so good. Now let's consider the backing track, it doesn't want to be the same volume as the presenters voice, this would be really distracting, so I want to lower that by some percentage. I can also do this with ffmpeg, I could do it like this (example would set volume to 50%):

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -af "volume=0.5" <output>
```

Using these two commands back to back, I can get the desired result.

My question has two parts:

1. Is there a way to do this in one step?
2. Is there any benefit to doing it in one step?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "Is there a way to do this in one step?" - have you tried it?

Comment: I _think_ this worked actually...

ffmpeg -i <input> -af "volume=xxxdB,volume=0.5" <output>

I didn't think it was working at first but now after trying with more samples, it might well be.

Answer (score 4):

After testing some more, I actually think the answer was pretty straight forward, I just needed to do this.

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -af "volume=xxxdB,volume=0.5" <output>
```

Took me a while to realize it, I had to try with a view samples before I felt confident.